# How do I use common UI styles in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, themes

I am writing my little Android app. I pop up a dialog control which is a nice, non-fullscreen, rounded-corners dialog by setting `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` on the activity in my manifest. That all works just as I expected. However it is just a drab, grey-titled dialog as in this screenshot:

[image: default grey dialog look]

I've noticed however that a LOT of applications, when they pop up dialogs have a nice, blue-themed title as in this screen shot.

[image]

I would assume this theme is some common theme, as it shows up in a LOT of different apps. I would assume it is something built in to the OS. (My phone is a Captivate with the official Froyo release). Of course it COULD be something that every developer simply re-coded on their own, but I doubt that.

Assuming that this is a common theme, how do I utilize it in my app? What changes do I need to make to my activity to have it use that theme?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your activity to use a default theme like Theme.Black.  There are default themes and they are in R.style - although i'm not sure which are available to which platforms(i.e. i think the holo themes are for 3.0 and up...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html

see here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html for defining your own custom themes and scroll all the way down for using the "platform styles" and themes.

Comment: So, what if you want some of the components from two styles; can you somehow "OR" them together? Or would you simply define your own custom style inheriting from the "larger" theme you want to inherit and then tweak it, as per the "Defining Styles" section of the second link?

Comment: I would define either define my own style, inheriting the closest matched predefined.  You can set themes on individual components one at a time where you want them but would be cumbersome and likely lead to an inconsistent look and feel.

Comment: This looks like what I'll need to do I guess... probably implemented much as this guy did his common appearance: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/ . Thanks for the directioning!

Answer (score 0):

Rather messy (there doesn't seem to be a good reference for this), but the platform styles are defined in \platforms\android-\data\res\values\styles.xml and \platforms\android-\data\res\values\themes.xml. You can dig through those and figure out the theme/style IDs that are available at compile time.

Other than that its really just trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

To make a dialog you need to extend the dialog class. And to have a nice title bar you can use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

and have your own custom title.

to have a title use:

```
setTitle("MyTitle");
```

You can also assign your custom view for the title.

Comment: I actually want to apply this styling to the activity which will be the main activity of my application. Essentially I want my window to emulate the look of the "Add Shortcut" dialog from the home screen. The Dialog class looks like it needs to be launched from another activity? It doesn't seem to actually BE an activity from what I can tell from this doc-url: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html